# Python's urllib equivalent in .net

Tags: .net, python, webclient

Is there a .net equivalent for urllib I used in Python?

I've seen WebRequest and WebResponse classes but I wonder if there is a simpler wrapper. In urllib you can use dictionary object (tupple) to set POST parameters while in .Net one must fiddle with streams.

Is there any free, small web client library available for .net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Webclient`'s [`UploadValues()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx) or [`UploadString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0645045y.aspx).